# Why does leaking truck keep same speed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, momentum, conservation-laws

[image]

Why this is the right answer? As we know liner momentum is conserved so:

$$V_1 M_1=V_2M_2$$

and since truck is leaking oil $M_2$ is less than $M_1$, let $M_1=10$ and $M_2=8$
then 
$$V_1\cdot10=V_2\cdot8\implies V_1=0.8\cdot V_2$$
and that means that the speed while leaking is faster.

Comment: Isn’t an oil tanker a big boat carrying oil, hence the mention of water?

Comment: @innisfree: I was wondering about that too. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: I think that "water" is typo and they meant "oil" in the question.

Comment: @Balawi28 It is a boat in the water leaking oil

Answer (score 6):

If the oil was being emitted at some horizontal speed that is non-zero relative to the tanker, then you would be correct. This would mean that a force is required to change the horizontal velocity of the oil, which by N3L means a force is exerted on the tanker and hence its velocity would change.

However, if the oil is just leaking, i.e. falling down out of the tanker, then there would be no horizontal force acting on the oil or the tanker. Hence it keeps it's constant horizontal speed.

The question should have been more specific on how the oil was leaking out.

Comment: Wow. So far we've had a truck, a boat and now a train! ;-)

Comment: @Gert sorry it was a typo. I had it correct in the rest of the answer

Comment: Really thanks for your answer and your time, you're totally correct if you're talking about a stationary truck, but if we assumed that it's moving at constant velocity (engine is giving the wheels specific force to move) then losing mass means that we have same force by engine but less mass and since (F=ma) that means more acceleration hence more speed.

Comment: @Balawi28 It's not a truck, it's a boat. Plus, there is no mention of the action of an engine. The momentum of the oil which is leaking is carried out of the boat at the same rate that the mass is decreasing. System momentum remains constant.

Comment: Yes, the question is a bit vague. A common variant of this question features a moving cart leaking sand vertically. There are several questions of that form on the site.

Comment: @Balawi28 If the tanker is moving at a constant horizontal speed then there is no force acting on it. If the oil falls out of it vertically then it imparts no force on it. Therefore the tanker keeps the same speed. If you want to use $F=ma$, then you need to notice that $F_x=0$, so $a_x$ = 0.